# Determine position of circle with another circle

Tags: geometry

I am trying to solve this geometry problem but am kind of stuck.

We have three circles $(c_1, c_2, c_3)$ of radii $r_1$, $r_2$, and $r_3$. Where $r_1 > r_2 > r_3$. Circle $c_3$ is in contact with $c_1$ and $c_2$ at only one point each. With the coordinate system drawn below, $c_1$ has center $(0,0)$ and $c_2$ has center $(0,-r_1+r_2)$. I attached a sketch below. How would I find the center of $c_3$?

[image: Problem sketch]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What've you tried?

Comment: Well I drew the sketch mainly. Then I drew some lines and some triangles but it didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Surely triangles will help. We have two unknowns $x,y$ and two right triangles so

$$(y+r_1-r_2)^2+x^2=(r_2+r_3)^2$$
$$y^2+x^2=(r_1-r_3)^2$$

I will leave the calculation as it is pretty messy. One way to speed up a little bit is to use the identity $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$ instead of expand the whole thing out to find $y$ first but to find $x$ you still need to do the hard work.